# The buttons can't be clicked after I added the user interface and hp-bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a game using html, javascript and css. The visuals work fine and I know that the buttons DO work because before I could click on them fine and it would run the javascript function. I haven't touched the javascript since.  There is something off with my html or css that doesn't allow me to click on my buttons at all. Here is my code.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script defer src="cyber.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        
        <div class="parent"></div>
        
        <!-- Represents health bar of user -->
        <div class="user-interface" id="userInterface"> 
            <div class="stat">
            <h1 style="font-size: 16px">user name</h1>
            <div class="stat-bg">
                <div class="interface-back"></div>
                <div class="user-hp"id="userHealthBar"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <canvas class="game-canvas"></canvas>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div id="text" class="text">Text</div>
            <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
                <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 4</button>
            </div>
        <div>
        
        
          
        
        
        
    </div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
  outline: 1px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transform: scale (3) translateY(50%);
  display: inline-block;
}
.parent {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 10;
}
.game-canvas {
  background-color: black;
  height: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;


}
.user-interface {
  z-index: 20;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.stat {
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 4px black dotted;
  padding: 5px;
}
.stat-bg {
  position: relative
}
.interface-back{
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc; 
  
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right: 0;
}
.user-hp{
  height: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.bottom {
  height: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 4px white solid;
  display: flex;
}
.text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 66.66%;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}


.btn-grid {
  width: 33.33%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-left: 4px white solid;
}

.btn {
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.3);
  border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 44%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: black;
}
```

I tried shifting this html code around:

```
<div class="bottom">
    <div id="text" class="text">Text</div>
        <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
                <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 4</button>
        </div>
     </div>
<div>
```

it contains all my buttons. It led to my user interface/ hp bar appearing at the bottom where my text would be and my buttons and text would disappear.  I like the code as is, I just want to be able to press buttons so I quickly gave that up. I then resorted to deleting and redoing each code in css for an hour but nothing with the buttons changed or maybe I overlooked it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, all I needed to do is delete both z-index in my CSS!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).